# usernames in google auth flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am facing the following problem: I am displaying the username of the google account of the user in a subtitle in a list tile, but the code that I use displays an error if the user is not logged in first, so how can I edit this code to display you are not logged in when the user is not logged in or is logged out. Also, how to display the username of the google account if the user is signed in or changed his account this is the code:

```
subtitle: new FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return new Text(snapshot.data.displayName);
              }
              else {
                return new Text('you are not logged in');
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing the problem

You can simply replace `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting` with `snapshot.hasData`, which [is the equivalent of `snpashot.data != null`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L255). This, however, will display `'you are not logged in'` even when still waiting. I added a `'loading'` `Text` for waiting:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return Text('loading');
  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Text('you are not logged in');
  } else {
    return Text(snapshot.data.displayName);
  }
}
```

This works because [`currentUser()` returns `null` if there is no current user](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L279).

#### A suggestion

You are currently using `currentUser()`, which does not update on authentication changes. You can use [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L115), which is a stream that will update ***every** time* and always provide you with the latest user. For this, you will have to migrate to `StreamBuilder`:

```
subtitle: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text('loading');
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('you are not logged in');
              } else {
                return Text(snapshot.data.displayName);
              }
            },
          )
```

Comment: this code is good but the text doesnt change unless I close the app from the task manager then reopen it can you suggest another edit creativecreatorormaybenot

Comment: @serjomacken Done.